# Procedure for importing Web access login data in Weka or RapidMinder

Tags: weka, rapidminer

Please excuse my ignorance. I am a beginner user of Weka and RapidMiner for academic purposes.

The file format is simple .txt format. I have web access login of a certain web site and it has following fields along with other information:

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 7.5
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2015-02-23 00:03:19

#Fields: date time s-sitename s-computername s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs-version cs(User-Agent) cs(Cookie) cs(Referer) cs-host sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status sc-bytes cs-bytes time-taken
```

(after each space new field starts)

Therefore, my question is that if there is a way to import such data which has these certain fields (separated by spaces)? Also, some attributes may have "-", would that be catered for somehow?

Answer (score 0):

If it's guaranteed there are no spaces within the attribute names and there is no chance that the individual data values themselves contain spaces then you could use the RapidMiner `Read CSV` operator. Run the import configuration wizard and select space as the column separation method.

Comment: Yes that is guaranteed. But the file format is .txt. May I save it as .csv simply and then import it in RapidMiner?

Comment: You can access it directly without renaming.

Comment: In RapidMiner Studio 6.3.0, it only gives options for .csv, excel sheet, xml file, access database table, database table and binary file, to import into a repository.

Comment: The `Read CSV` operator is not restricted to CSV files only. When selecting the file to open in the open file dialog, select `All Files` or you can just type the name of the file directly into the parameter.